# Edit the Label of the selected item of the ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to edit the Label value according to the value of the selected Slider of the ListView. When the Slider has a value greater than 2 and less than 20 the text of the Label should change to "Edited"
The only thing I have is the following code attached.
Could it be done differently?

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    readonly List<Tarea> listaTarea = new List<Tarea>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        llenarLista();

        listaEjemplo.ItemsSource = listaTarea;
    }
    public void llenarLista()
    {

        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea{
            nombre = "Alex1",
            valor="10",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex2",
            valor = "20",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex3",
            valor = "30",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex4",
            valor = "40",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex5",
            valor = "50",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        /*
        if(listaTarea[2].valor.Equals("30"))
        {
            listaTarea[2].descripcion = "Cambiado";
        }*/
    }
    void Handle_ValueChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sliders = sender as Slider;
        var item = sliders.Parent.BindingContext as Tarea;
        double valor = sliders.Value;


        if(valor > 2 && valor<20)
        {
            item.nombre = "Editado";
        }
    }
}
```

Attached the XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="listaEjemplo" HasUnevenRows="True">  
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate>  
            <ViewCell>  
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">  
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">  
                        <Label Text="{Binding nombre}" Font="18"></Label> 
                        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="20" ValueChanged="Handle_ValueChanged"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding descripcion}" TextColor="Gray"></Label> </StackLayout>  
                </StackLayout>  
            </ViewCell>  
        </DataTemplate>  
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
As Ivan said , you can use `Converter`

Refer to the following code.

```
public class ValueToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((double)value < 20 && (double)value > 2)
        {
            return "Editado";
        }

        return "Ejemplo";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The Convert method is called when data moves from the source to the target in **OneWay** or **TwoWay** bindings. The value parameter is the object or value from the data-binding source. The method must return a value of the type of the data-binding target.

**in xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ValueToTextConverter x:Key="ValueToText" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listaEjemplo" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding nombre}" Font="18"></Label>
                            <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="20" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},
                                Path=Value,
                                Converter={StaticResource ValueToText}}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two more ways to do it:

- Bind the `Slider` `Value` with `TwoWay` `Mode`. Then in the setters of the value change the value bound to the label (in that part similar to what you did in the code above)
- Bind the `Label` `Value` to `Slider` `Value` and declare the `Converter` class that will convert `Slider` `Value` to the desired `Label` `Value`.